# How can I compile a java file on my Android Emulator?

Tags: android, compiler-construction, permissions

I have a java file on my android emulator and I need to compile it on the emulator terminal. Whenever I write "javac filename.java" I get an error message saying: "Permission denied".

Comment: I don't think you can. Android has the Dalvik VM but no JDK

Comment: Where do you write? You can't compile a source file on the emulator since there is no Java for Android.

Comment: Do you think there is anyway I can install the JDK to the emulator?

Comment: Why would you want to compile Java code *on an emulator*? You already have a Java development environment, on your development machine. Even if you could do it, it would take many times as long as building it normally on your development machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this. When you compile a java source file it is first complied into a .class file which is Java byte code. After that the class files are then compiled again into a .dex file which is the Dalvik byte code which the Dalvik virtual machine can run. This .dex file is then compressed into an .apk file which is the archive which contain all your application's data. You can read more about it [here](http://www.ctoedge.com/content/how-dalvik-virtual-machine-works-google-android).

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking at [Terminal IDE](http://www.spartacusrex.com/terminalide.htm), although on the emulator, I can't imagine it will be much fun.

In theory, it should work, if slowly. It's java/javac/apkbuilder/etc. with vim, and doesn't require rooting.

Comment: Your post was very much beneficial and thank you for the link.
I just need to ask you if you have experienced using this tool previously, and if yes, do you know how can we start the "vim" from the src/ folder?

Comment: @user1149428 Haven't used it on an emulator; that would be crazy. It's a command line, and vim is an executable, you should be able to start it from anywhere.