# How to run a Java File in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android

I have created an android project in Eclipse indigo 3.7.2. The project runs successfully. Now I have added a new java class file called test.java with the following contents

```
public class test
{
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           System.out.println("Hello World");
       }
}
```

Please tell me how to run this file android emulator

Comment: You should really do a bit more research before asking a question here. A simple 2 minute search would have given you the answer to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this. When you compile a java source file it is first complied into a .class file which is Java byte code. After that the class files are then compiled again into a .dex file which is the Dalvik byte code which the Dalvik virtual machine can run. This .dex file is then compressed into an .apk file which is the archive which contain all your application's data. You can read more about it [here](http://www.itbusinessedge.com/).

Source [How can I compile a java file on my Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863424/how-can-i-compile-a-java-file-on-my-android-emulator) . Originally answered by Stefan Bossbaly.

Answer (score 2):

Android does not expose the `classic Java Main` method. It rilies on the concept of `Activity` (the old Applet concept) with its lifecycle. You should read the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) about.

Comment: Indeed. Please read quite some pages of [the Android developer guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) and then come back when you're stuck at a specific topic :)

Comment: Thank you  for your answer blackbelt. I am completely new to Android. Please tell me Will statement such as System.out.println("Hello World") work in android?

Comment: Thanks MarchingHome for the Android developer guides

Comment: No that statement will not work. You will have to use the `Log` class to debug. You will learn about this when reading the guides. Good luck! Android is fun :)

Comment: use Log is the way to go, but I the System.out is part of the Android framework, so it should works

Answer (score 0):

First of all even android is java based
but not all java class and platform is supported in android (like Java ME classes, AWT or Swing)

in your case you trying to use java.lang package with using

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

default java output streams like System.out or System.err won't show's anything
android developer encouraged to use log and see it in the log cat

and I think you also need to understand the whole concept of android platform (what is android res,assets,layout,etc)

in your case you want to show a hello world,it means you need to create a textview (you can create it from the java file or the xml file) and set the textview into "hello world"

if you want to study android please see this page->http://developer.android.com/index.html

for the tutorial you can search it in the internet there are so many android tutorial in the web